# How To Get The Value Inside td using custom attribute

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to get the value of custom attribute which is inside the td tag

when i click the update button the popup will show and the value should be inserted in the textbox everything is working but i am not been able to get the value of td which has custom attribute

```
echo "<td class='tdid'  id='test' userid='$id'>".$row["id"]."</td>";
echo "<td class='tdtext' id='test' check='$id'>".$row["name"]."</td>";
echo "<td><Button style='margin-left:10px;' class='btn btn-primary buttonclass' tayyab='$name'>edit</Button>
```

jquery code of update button

```
$(".buttonclass").click(function(){
   $('#dialog').dialog('open');
   var edit=$(this).attr("tayyab");
   $("#textbox").val(edit);
   $(".showtext").val(edit);

   var labelid=$(this).attr("userid");  
   $(".u_id").val(labelid);
   alert(labelid);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, `this` refers to `button` and not `td`.

```
$(this).attr("userid");
```

Try this:

```
$(this).parents('tr').find('td[userid]').attr("userid");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the `td` element using `this` on the button click event where `this` refers to the button and not the `td`.

So you have to change your selector like this, `$(this).closest('tr').find('td:has([userid])')`

Give a try at the below code,

```
$(".buttonclass").click(function(){


            $('#dialog').dialog('open');
            var edit=$(this).attr("tayyab");
            $("#textbox").val(edit);
            $(".showtext").val(edit);

            var labelid = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:has([userid])').attr("userid"); 
            $(".u_id").val(labelid);
            alert(labelid);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want custom attribute in your HTML page, then it should suffix with `data-`. For example, in your case instead of `tayyab` use `data-tayyab`. And in JS you can fetch the attribute value by 2 way,

By simply `attr();`

```
var edit=$(this).attr("data-tayyab");
```

Or by `data();`

```
var edit=$(this).data("tayyab");
```

And in your code, `id = 'test'` is not unique. Keep remember, id should be unique in one page.

```
echo "<td class='tdid'  id='test' userid='$id'>".$row["id"]."</td>";
echo "<td class='tdtext' id='test' check='$id'>".$row["name"]."</td>";
```

To fetch `userid` attribute, you can do like this,

```
echo "<td class='tdid'  id='test1' data-userid='$id'>".$row["id"]."</td>";
echo "<td class='tdtext' id='test2' data-check='$id'>".$row["name"]."</td>";

var userID = $("#test1").attr('data-userid');
```

Hope this will clear and will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

try this change `tayyab="'.$name.'"` instead of `tayyab='$name'` and button instead of Button. Last echo was not terminate with semicolon `;`

And apply with `$(this).closest('tr').find('td[userid]').attr("userid");`

its find the attribute from the place of parent

```
echo "<td class='tdid'  id='test' userid='".$id."'>".$row["id"]."</td>";
echo "<td class='tdtext' id='test' check='".$id."'>".$row["name"]."</td>";
echo "<td><button style='margin-left:10px;' class='btn btn-primary buttonclass' tayyab='".$name."'>edit</button>";
```

jquery code of update button

```
  $(".buttonclass").click(function(){


            $('#dialog').dialog('open');
            var edit=$(this).attr("tayyab");
            $("#textbox").val(edit);
            $(".showtext").val(edit);

            var labelid=$(this).closest('tr').find('td[userid]').attr("userid");  
            $(".u_id").val(labelid);
            alert(labelid);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

go up the dom three using `parent()` and use find to get `.tdid` who has the `userid` attribute:

```
var labelid=$(this).parent().find('.tdid[userid]').attr("userid");
```